# How to perform left join so every record from left table will be fetched irrespective of where condition on right table

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I am trying to fetch details of pages stored in `pages` table in database.

I want to fetch all records from `page` table and the records having `user_id` 16 from `pages_commission` table.

The query I tried

`` SELECT pages.*, IFNULL(pc.commission, 0) AS commission FROM `pages` LEFT JOIN `pages_commission` AS pc ON pages.page_id=pc.page_id WHERE pc.user_id=16 ``

But I am gettings zero rows.

### Table structure:

1. `pages` table

[image: pages tale]

2. `pages_commission` table

[image: pages_commission]

**Database:** MySql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` is turning the join into an inner join.  Move the constant condition to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.*, COALESCE(pc.commission, 0) AS commission
FROM `pages` p LEFT JOIN
     `pages_commission`pc
     ON p.page_id = pc.page_id AND pc.user_id = 16;
```